# UNIX Sort Command

Tags: sorting, unix

I need to sort the data in a file. Sort order is Column 7,2.  The last column (Column 8) is null:

```
    1|1|1|1|1|1|12333|    
    3|3|3|3|3|3|44454|    
    2|2|2|2|2|2|22222|    
    1|1|1|1|1|1|123300000|
```

When I use the following command I get a strange value in the output file:

```
sort -o /test1/FILE2 -T /test1/Junk -t\| -k7,7 -k2,2 /test1/Junk/FILE2_1
```

Where

- `/test1/FILE2` is the input file
- `/test1/Junk` is the temporary directory
- `/test1/Junk/FILE2_1` is the output file

Values in the output file

```
    1|1|1|1|1|1|123300000|    
    1|1|1|1|1|1|12333|    
    2|2|2|2|2|2|22222|    
    3|3|3|3|3|3|44454|
```

Any idea why the row containing 123300000 is coming up first?

I need the sorting like below:

```
    1|1|1|1|1|1|12333|    
    1|1|1|1|1|1|123300000|    
    2|2|2|2|2|2|22222|    
    3|3|3|3|3|3|44454|
```

Answer (score 4):

Normally, you choose either numeric or lexicographical (dictionary) ordering.

If you wanted those values sorted numerically, you would need a `-n` in your `sort` command:

```
pax> echo '1|1|1|1|1|1|12333|    
3|3|3|3|3|3|44454|    
2|2|2|2|2|2|22222|    
1|1|1|1|1|1|123300000|' | sort -t \| -k7,7 -k2,2 -n

1|1|1|1|1|1|12333|    
2|2|2|2|2|2|22222|    
3|3|3|3|3|3|44454|    
1|1|1|1|1|1|123300000|
```

---

If, on the other hand, you *don't* want it sorted numerically, then the output you have is *already* correct as far as I can see:

```
                v
1|1|1|1|1|1|123300000|    
1|1|1|1|1|1|12333|    
                ^
```

Note the highlighted characters. Since `0` comes before `3`, this is the *right* lexicographical order.

Changing that large value to `123330000` results in the order you seem to be after:

```
pax> echo '1|1|1|1|1|1|12333|    
3|3|3|3|3|3|44454|    
2|2|2|2|2|2|22222|    
1|1|1|1|1|1|123330000|' | sort -t \| -k7,7 -k2,2

1|1|1|1|1|1|12333|    
1|1|1|1|1|1|123330000|
2|2|2|2|2|2|22222|    
3|3|3|3|3|3|44454|
```

Hence I suspect you're just misreading the data in this case.

---

If, as you state in a comment, the test data was incorrect, the presence or absence of the final `|` character should make no difference to the sort order. First, lexicographical sorting with and without `|`:

```
pax> echo ; echo '1|1|1|1|1|1|12333|
3|3|3|3|3|3|44454|
2|2|2|2|2|2|22222|
1|1|1|1|1|1|123330000|' | sort -t \| -k7,7 -k2,2

1|1|1|1|1|1|12333|
1|1|1|1|1|1|123330000|
2|2|2|2|2|2|22222|
3|3|3|3|3|3|44454|

pax> echo ; echo '1|1|1|1|1|1|12333
3|3|3|3|3|3|44454
2|2|2|2|2|2|22222
1|1|1|1|1|1|123330000' | sort -t \| -k7,7 -k2,2

1|1|1|1|1|1|12333
1|1|1|1|1|1|123330000
2|2|2|2|2|2|22222
3|3|3|3|3|3|44454
```

You can see there that `123330000` is second in both cases.

Similarly, for numerical sorting with and without `|`, the larger number appears at the end:

```
pax> echo ; echo '1|1|1|1|1|1|12333| 
3|3|3|3|3|3|44454| 
2|2|2|2|2|2|22222| 
1|1|1|1|1|1|123330000|' | sort -t \| -k7,7 -k2,2 -n

1|1|1|1|1|1|12333|
2|2|2|2|2|2|22222|
3|3|3|3|3|3|44454|
1|1|1|1|1|1|123330000|

pax> echo ; echo '1|1|1|1|1|1|12333 
3|3|3|3|3|3|44454 
2|2|2|2|2|2|22222 
1|1|1|1|1|1|123330000' | sort -t \| -k7,7 -k2,2 -n

1|1|1|1|1|1|12333
2|2|2|2|2|2|22222
3|3|3|3|3|3|44454
1|1|1|1|1|1|123330000
```

If you're seeing something else then either your sort is broken or it's configured strangely. You might want to investigate, if that's the case, whether you have a `sort` function or alias overriding the real one (with `which sort`, for example), or whether you have a bizarre `LC_ALL` setting, which affects the comparison function used for sorting.

With GNU sort, at least, you can also use `--debug` to annotate the output, indicating which line portions are used as keys.

And, finally, one other possibility may be the presence of non-printing characters in your input that may be affecting sort order. You can detect these by getting a hex dump of the file and checking it:

```
od -xcb /test1/Junk/FILE2_1
```

Comment: If there is no 8th column then I am getting the desired result. This means if the last column (NULL) is not there then the result is             1|1|1|1|1|1|12333                                                              1|1|1|1|1|1|123300000                                                               2|2|2|2|2|2|22222   
3|3|3|3|3|3|44454                                                                                                                I want to know whether the last column with NULL value is impacting the sorting.

Comment: @Aravindh, if you're getting `123300000` after `12333` for anything other than numeric sorting (or some bizarre correlation settings which don't seem to be the case here), your sort is broken.

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake. the correct data is                                     1|1|1|1|1|1|12333|    
3|3|3|3|3|3|44454|    
2|2|2|2|2|2|22222|    
1|1|1|1|1|1|123330000|                                                                                                            Assuming if the 8th column is not there then the result is                                 1|1|1|1|1|1|12333                                                          1|1|1|1|1|1|123330000  
2|2|2|2|2|2|22222
3|3|3|3|3|3|44454

Comment: @Aravindh, then that is the correct result since you've specified lexicographical sorting. The presence or absence of a `|` at the end of each line makes no difference to the sort order on my system, either with or without `-n` (`-n` itself changes the sort order, but the `|` is not affecting that). If it does on yours, `sort` is broken, which should be investigated.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
I tried some scenarios in the unix box and got the below result. Second one is strange.

1.printf "1|12\n1|120\n"|sort -t \| -k2,2

Expected:
1|12
1|120

Actual result:
1|12
1|120

2.printf "1|12|\n1|120|\n"|sort -t \| -k2,2

Expected:
1|12|
1|120|

Actual Result:
1|120|
1|12|

3.printf "1|12||\n1|120||\n"|sort -t \| -k2,2

Expected:
1|12||
1|120||

Actual Result:
1|12||
1|120||

When I tried the same scenarios in a UNIX cygwin64 terminal then I am getting the desired result (Expected result).

Comment: Second one, I get `1|12|` *then* `1|120|` (Debian Linux) so your results *are* strange. What do you get from `which sort`, `sort --version`, `echo $LC_ALL` and trying it with `--debug` flag?

Comment: I am sorry. I could not get the result for 2 commands.                        which sort
/bin/sort

sort --version
error. option is incorrect

echo $LC_ALL
parameter not set

--debug flag
error. option is incorrect

Comment: @Aravindh, then you're not using GNU sort, And the version you have seems to not be behaving as per normal sort. Suggest you download GNU sort and use that, or check the man page for your variant.

Answer (score 0):

The Ordering is done lexicographical as you said. Your command is almost correct but use n in sort command, like,

```
3|3|3|3|3|3|44454|
2|2|2|2|2|2|22222|
1|1|1|1|1|1|123330000|' | sort -t \| -nk7,7 -nk2,2

This will sort the data numerically.
```